# In which case my Excel Range.OutlineLevel is null or System.DBNull?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, vsto

In my VSTO add-in code I have a range.outlinelevel check for my worksheet rows. 
According to the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-3b03f3a0-d000-4f7c-9181-be4355959d90) the outline level could be 1 to 8 and is of the type [Variant/Double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff838455.aspx).

1. But sometimes there is returned **null**
2. And other times range.OutlineLevel.GetType() returns **DBNull**

**Does someone know why/when this is the case?**

---

A related post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778183/fastest-way-to-get-the-highest-range-outlinelevel-in-an-excel-worksheet

Comment: link to the MSDN? [Range.OutlineLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838455(v=office.15).aspx) is a read/write Variant from what I see.

Comment: @vba4all Yes it's a variant, but that's not my question. Normally the VariantType of this variant is Double, but SOMETIMES it is not (see above). I want to know in which cases...

Comment: share link to the MSDN about what you have just read. btw. Variant can become anything.

Comment: @Meehow I've added two links. I'm still looking for an answer to that question...

Answer (score 1):

I still have no answer to (1.). 
But today I've found an answer to (2.):

A range.OutlineLevel.GetType() returns DBNull, if there are multiple outline levels in the given range.

See the debugger output below:

- The standard OutlineLevel for a normal row is 1.0:

  ```
  range.OutlineLevel  1.0     dynamic {double}
  ```
- For multiple rows with different OutlineLevels the result is:

  ```
  range.OutlineLevel  {}      dynamic {System.DBNull}
  ```